# Using link_to helper to link to a parent view from child view - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> So basically I'm trying to use `link_to` helper to link to a
>   **parent** view from a **child** view.

I have the current relationship

```
Place has_many :experiences
Experience belongs_to :place
```

In my experience view(show.html.erb) I have a button that I want to link to a place view. Currently, this experience is associated to a place (**Parent** being place and experience being the **child**)

```
<%= link_to 'Place', @place %>
```

My experience controller

```
def show
   @place = Place.find(params[:id])
end
```

I get the following error

> Couldn't find Experience with 'id'=Place

I'm not sure how to craft the @place to link to a place id. So how would I call a place view from the experience view?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the place linked to the experience so your controller should actually look like this

```
class ExperiencesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @experience = Experience.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then you can access the place through the @experience object

`<%= link_to 'Place', @experience.place %>`

Comment: This seems very close, although I'm still getting the same error. "Couldn't find Experience with 'id'=Place". For some reason I have this same variable call in my set_experience method that was auto generated?

Comment: is set_experience called from a before_action/before_filter callback?

Comment: What do your routes look like and what url are you visiting

Comment: `params[:id]` will be retrieved from the url, so it seems as though you are visiting a malformed url. Your url should look something like `/place/12/experience/24` but it seems you are visiting something like `/place/12/experience/Place`. It's possible something strange is happening to your route so check your routes.rb file for the correlating definition

Comment: I'm trying to call place GET    /places/:id(.:format)             places#show from my experience view.

Comment: What is the url for the experience view, the one you are visiting? does it say Place anywhere in it?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and show me the routes. Create a http://gist.github.com